# array_intersect always evaluates to false

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, intersect

my code always goes into the "else-part", even if the "if-part" should be returned. When i delete the "else-part" it returns the "if-part".

```
  foreach ($messageRepo as $oMessage) {
    $messageTag = $oMessage->getMessageTags(); // get tags from all messages   
    $storeTagsUnseri = unserialize($messageTag); // unserialize tags given by the user
    $storeTagsUnseri = (array)($storeTagsUnseri);        

    if (array_intersect($messageTagsArray,$storeTagsUnseri)) {  //if tags from user matches tags from DB messages
      $messageToTag[] = $oMessage->getMessageText();     // get the message text from the DB message and store it in array
      $messageCrdate[] = $oMessage->getCrdate();

      $allMessagesArray = array_flip(array_combine($messageToTag,$messageCrdate));
      return $allMessagesArray;
    } else {
      $allMessagesArray[] = "flummi";
      return $allMessagesArray;
    }    
  }
```

This code always returns $allMessageArray 0 => "flummi" even if array_intersect is true.

Maybe if(array_intersect) is not possible at all? Is there another way to check if anything in one array matches in another array?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

```
      foreach ($messageRepo as $oMessage) {
    $messageTag = $oMessage->getMessageTags(); // get tags from all messages   
    $storeTagsUnseri = unserialize($messageTag); // unserialize tags given by the user
    $storeTagsUnseri = (array)($storeTagsUnseri);        

    if (array_intersect($messageTagsArray,$storeTagsUnseri)) {  //if tags from user matches tags from DB messages
      $messageToTag[] = $oMessage->getMessageText();     // get the message text from the DB message and store it in array
      $messageCrdate[] = $oMessage->getCrdate();

      $allMessagesArray = array_flip(array_combine($messageToTag,$messageCrdate)); 
    }      
  }

  if (!empty($allMessagesArray)) {
      return $allMessagesArray;
  } else {
      return $allMessagesArray[] = "error";
  }


}
```

This works now...but not very good coding i guess. ^^

Comment: Print your both array above your if condition & kindly show us.

Comment: Please `var_dum $messageTagsArray,$storeTagsUnseri` in your question

Comment: I guess, the problem in that array_intersect returns array and not true/false. Its a guess though.

Comment: $messageTagsArray
array(1 item)
   0 => 'fre' (3 chars)
$storeTagsUnseri
array(3 items)
   0 => 'lkklkl' (6 chars)
   1 => 'kdsfgsdfg' (9 chars)
   2 => 'sdfgsdfggg' (10 chars)

Comment: The intersection of those arrays is empty, so it should go to the else-part.

Comment: @BhavikShah empty arrays are treated as false, non-empty arrays are true.

Comment: But when i delete the else-part i get the correct array...array(1 item)
   1357229130 => 'getr' (4 chars)

Comment: Why are you `return`ing inside a `foreach` anyway? Sounds like your surrounding logic is screwed up.

Comment: Yes, i think my logic is screwed up...could you help me?

Comment: RE your edit, why not just push the `error` element onto the array before the loop?

Comment: I re-edit my question. It's enough when the array is empty. Sometimes one think too complicated. :)

Comment: Can you also add your question what `var_dump(array_intersect($messageTagsArray,$storeTagsUnseri));` outputs, so that we can see what's really happening there.